# Split data of columns in (if of is not null data of is null)

Tags: sql

```
list    dept_no 
-----   -------
kamam       200
salam       300
galam       400
```

The Required table is:

```
id        dept_no
-----     -------
kamam      null
null       200 
salam      null
null       300
galam      null
null
```

Comment: Do you want to have `NULL` in your `Id` column (assume `Id` is PK)?

Comment: yes assume Id is not PK)

Comment: @user1856629 is that data in the same table? or is it in different tables?  Please post your table structure.

Comment: emp((id number, (PK), list varchar) dept(id number(fk), dept_no number)

Comment: @user1856629 please format the question such that it's readable. [it looks like someone's already trying to help you and you're not accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14607295/revisions) so maybe you should do it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `UNION ALL` appears to be working:

```
select list, dept_no
from
(
  select id, list, null as dept_no
  from emp
  union all
  select id, null , dept_no
  from dept
) 
order by id, list
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db3b9/9)

Comment: @user1856629 glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want this union all?

```
select id, NULL as dept_no
from t
union all
select NULL as id, dept_no
from t
```

Comment: i dont want union all i want to split

Comment: @user1856629 . . . What does that mean?  This query produces exactly the data you state in the question based on the input data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want result in the below format:

```
t dept_no
1 null
null 200
2 null
null 300
3 null
null 400
```

Then Use the below query :

```
select t, NULL as dept_no
from table
union all
select NULL as t, dept_no
from table
```

Comment: it is not working can you write the table name as well

Comment: u can use your table if You are doing for testing then use DUAL